# Wild fly multiple datasource

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly

I testing migration from JBoss AS 7.0.1 to Wild Fly 8.2.0 final.
Reason : a log4j bug causing deadlocks on database; bug solved only in JBoss EAP I cannot use => Then Wild Fly seems a good candidate

I'm using **XA data sources** with **JTA transaction manager**

The configuration (standalone.xml)seems the same between JBoss AS 7.x and Wild Fly 8.2.x :

Data source 1

```
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DS_Habilitation" pool-name="DS_Habilitation" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=*****;databaseName=Habilitations_DV</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>*****</user-name>
                    <password>*******</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
```

Data Source 2

```
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DS_Referentiel" pool-name="DS_Referentiel" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=*****;databaseName=Referentiel_DV</connection-url>
            <driver>sqlserver</driver>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>true</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>*****</user-name>
                <password>******</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
```

Data Source 3

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DS_Sinistre" pool-name="DS_Sinistre" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=****;databaseName=Sinistres_DV</connection-url>
                    <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>******</user-name>
                        <password>******</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

I start Wild Fly and deploy my WAR correctly
When I login I call 2 datasources and I have the error :

```
ARJUNA012140: Adding multiple last resources is disallowed. Trying to add LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource
```

I solved this by adding in the "Wild Fly" server conf file standalone.xml:

```
   <system-properties>
      <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true"/>
   </system-properties>
```

Then I have warning indicating me transaction are unsafe because I've multiple datasources

```
WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-27) ARJUNA012141: Multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction. This is transactionally unsafe and should not be relied upon. Current resource is LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(
```

For information my services are like this (1 transation)

```
@Service("gestionnaireService") @Transactional(value="transactionManager")

    public class GestionnaireServiceImpl implements GestionnaireService {

        @Autowired
        private UtilisateurService utilisateurService;

        @Autowired
        private GestionnaireDao gestionnaireDao;
    .....
    }
```

Data source are like :

```
<bean id="dataSourceReferentiel" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/DS_Referentiel" />
    </bean>
...
<bean id="sessionFactoryReferentiel" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceReferentiel" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hibernate/referentiel/DonneeReference.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hibernate/referentiel/LibelleReference.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hibernate/referentiel/Localite.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>hibernate/referentiel/Banque.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <!-- Level 2 cache -->
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" >org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
...
<!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
```

- 1st point is with JBoss AS7 I did not have this problem wheras I should have
- 2nd I wonder if my datasources are correctly configured (XA) or if it's my services,...

Can you give me you opinion on this ?

Thanks

Comment: You say you are using xa-datasources, but your datasources are actually not defined in such a way, but `<datasource> ... </datasource>`. Should it not be `<xa-datasource>...</xa-datasource>` ?

Comment: Exact. I suspect datasource declaration to be incorrecte if XA datasource is what we want. XA is a legacy from the project we use. I wonder if it's really necessary. Our problematic is we have 3 database shemas and we need to ensure integrity of a transaction when we are working on all schemas.

Comment: Well if you need to access the three databases _within one transaction_ , you will probably need XA

Comment: I just need to ensure that if during a process where modifications are made on different schemas, that everything is not commited if an error occurs.

Comment: FWIW the log4j deadlock is ONLY if you use a `ConsoleAppender`. It wouldn't cause deadlocks with anything related to a DB.

Answer (score 1):

ok, thanks for you comments. I managed to avoid warning by setting separated transactions on services using not the same data source

```
@Service @Transactional(value="transactionManager", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class ReferenceServiceImpl implements ReferenceService {

    @Autowired
    private ReferenceDao dao;
...
}
```

I've tested that if it fails during the process, all transactions are rollbacked : fine

My last reflexion is do I really need to set XA datasource. My schemas are separated by I use same database instance. Don't know if one day we'll set shemas on different machines.

Anyways I would like to thanks this community for the help provided.